# jQueryUI DateTime picker , date format changes after selecting date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I have my viewmodel which is bound to my ASP.NET MVC form ,

```
 public class JobViewModels
    {
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
    }
```

View :

```
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "updatOverViewSection"
}))
                {
```

```
                        <tr>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartTime)
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndTime)
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label></label>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                }
            </div>
```

Functionality wise it works fine.But when I look at view, when page renders , it looks like following,

[image: Date time when page loaded]

But the moment I pick a date time from picker, it changes it's format to following. Now the only way I can think of working around is , have a string datetime property in model and call `startDateTime.ToString("DD-MM-YYYY hh:MM:ss")` , but this does not seem to be most efficient way and I could be wrong.

[image: Date time Selected]

Comment: Are you using [this addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)?

Comment: And do you want it to initially display as `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, No I am not using the add on and yes, initially I want to display as dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: What addon are you using - jQuery-UI does not have a datetimepicker (just a datepicker)?

Comment: My Bad @StephenMuecke, I am using jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js , it is on my layout,    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) of `@Html.TextBoxFor()` where the 2nd argument is a format string, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

alternatively, you can apply a `DisplayFormatAttribute` to your properties which will be respected by the `EditorFor()` method

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
```

As a side note, you use of `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control" })` will not ad a class attribute to the form control. It needs to be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

but adding html attributes using `EditorFor()` is only supported in MVC-5.1 or higher

Comment: Thanks, DisplayFormat works perfect, but HTMLFor, is  just creating an editable  text box , not a date pciker. And htnlattributes is a great tip :)

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment - both `TextBoxFor()` and `EditorFor()` in your case produce identical output i.e. `<input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" ..... />`. In order to generate the datetimepicker, you need to attach the plugin (which you are clearly already doing using for example `$('#StartDate').timepicker({ ....` It makes no difference if you use `EditorFor()` or `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: Will edit the question with screen shot and  could provide the html source generated.  Will check from my end as well..